# Having trouble subsetting with the ".loc[]" operator in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to subset a dataset to only rows where the "plays_sports" column is equal to "0." From what I understand, the ".loc[]" operator is the typical way of doing this in Python(/pandas) - I've successfully subsetted the dataset with respect to another column, but when I simply change the name of the column to "plays_sports" and leave the rest of the subsetting expression the same, it returns an empty subsetted-dataset, even though there are observations in the "plays_sports" equal to "0".

```
data.head()

past_score  dist    income  lab score   gender  race    income_bucket   plays_sports    student_id  lat long
0   8.091553    11.586920   67111.784934    0   7.384394    male    H   3   0   1   0.0 0.0
1   8.091553    11.586920   67111.784934    0   7.384394    male    H   3   0   1   0.0 0.0
2   7.924539    7858.126614 93442.563796    1   10.219626   F   W   4   0   2   0.0 0.0
3   7.924539    7858.126614 93442.563796    1   10.219626   F   W   4   0   2   0.0 0.0
4   7.726480    11.057883   96508.386987    0   8.544586    M   W   4   0   3   0.0 0.0
```

The following subsetting expression returns an empty dataset:

```
no_sports = data.loc[data["plays_sports"] == 0]

past_score  dist    income  lab score   gender  race    income_bucket   plays_sports
```

I've subsetted the data in similar ways already - why is isn't the data able to be subsetted in the same way here? How can(/pythonically should) I subset it here?

Here is a list of the unique values of "plays_sports":

```
data["plays_sports"].unique()

array(['0', '1', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'baseball', 'gymnastics',
       'tennis', 'volleyball'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: `no_sports = data.loc[data["plays_sports"] == '0']`

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you, that totally slipped right past me